# How does the interaction take place between a HSM,App Server and Database?

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, hsm

I have found all over the internet that HSM is the best place to store keys, but  I am left with many unanswered questions.How does interaction takes place between server,HSM and database?. Is it like the server retrieves the keys from HSM to decrypt the data from database? If we could retrieve the keys from HSM why do we need a HSM in between? we can use a secure DB to store keys.I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: A "a secure DB" is not secure, the attacker model to defend against is one who gains admin access to the server.

Comment: How does encryption and decryption take place at server?. Does the server distribute the encrypted data to DB and key to HSM while encrypting?. How does the process happen?.

Answer (score 0):

Different HSMs work differently.

Some store the keys internally but there are storage limitations. Some encrypt the keys and the encrypted keys are stored on the server.

Some will handle data encryption/decryption so the key is never outside the HSM.

HSMs also have different levels of hardening from attacks over the com port, hardware access (tampering: removing screws, etc), vibration/shock, heat, etc. When an attack is noticed the key encryption keys are erased.

Some have admin access control requiring multiple people to be present, each using a smart card and enter a password. Additional physical security may be provided by physical access control.

Comment: Does a server retrieve a key from HSM and decrypt the retrieved data from database?.

Comment: How do encryption and decryption take place at server?. Does the server distribute the encrypted data  to DB and key to HSM while encrypting?.  How does the process happen?.

Comment: @PrakashTadiparthi Exactly how depends on the particular, DB, server and HSM. If you are considering designing this yourself, don't, get a security professional to do the design and later vet your implementation.